# Python regex to match string

Tags: python, regex

I'm new here. Just having a problem with Python regex. 
I have a strings like

```
http://sample.com/test/id549268848?at=5
http://sample.com/test/id621311331?at=5
...
```

Can't find the right way to get only number after id and strip everything after.
Calling from the loop like this

```
self.splitAppId(rec[4])
```

Where rec[4] URL from list

The function itself:

```
def splitAppId(self, url):
        idMatch = re.search('/id(.*)?$', url)
        return idMatch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you doing wrong. Should be like this:

```
 def splitAppId(self, url):
        idMatch = re.search(r'/id([^/]+)\?[^/]*$', url)
        return idMatch.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If URL is format, then

```py
>>> "http://sample.com/test/id549268848?at=5".split('id')[-1].split('?')[0]
'549268848'
```